# How do i convert 100% into px in HTML

Tags: html, gwt, layout, column-width

I am making a slider based component in GWT.

```
Parent : width = 100%
.-------------------------------------------------.
| .---------------------------------------------. |
| |     Child : width = X                       | |
| '---------------------------------------------' |
'-------------------------------------------------'
```

where X = (parent's width in px) - (some calculations based on runtime);

My code says:

```
int providedWidth = parentContainer.getOffsetWidth();
```

In Firefox, I get the width correctly as (say) 345px
But in IE6, it constantly returns the width as 0 no matter what size it is.

From GWT perspective,
Parent is an AbsolutePanel placed within a DockPanel (super parent),
Child is a a HorizontalPanel.

I haven't placed code here for brevity, is there any other way to get the width or am
I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but maybe the element needs "layout" in IE6? Can you give it `style='zoom:1'`?

Comment: I was about to suggest that. +1

Comment: Does not work,
But its a great out-of-the box suggestion: to invoke hasLayout() method.

Man I wish this would work,
But, IE still reports it as 0.

Comment: on similar lines, i provided a border to it using ie developer tools and it suddenly popped out !!

maybe the hasLayout was not triggered until then...

Answer (score 2):

In IE you sometimes have to get the size information in a DeferredCommand because IE only does the layout after the event thread is done.

Comment: What is the type of the parent container ? Is that one really 100% of the browser window ?